# windows7からsambaサーバへ接続ができなくなった

Tags: samba

クライアント:Windows7 Professional
ーーーーー
こちらのサイトに書き込んで良い内容なのかわからないのですが、
以下の事象について、解決方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

現在の状況から、クライアントの何がしかの設定に問題があるのではないかと考えております。
ーーーーー

現在、社内のsambaのサーバは active directory の認証情報を利用して接続するようになっているのですが、先日私のアカウントのパスワードを変更した後、sambaのサーバに接続できなくなってしまいました。
※sambaサーバを構築した担当者が不在で、設定資料などないので、ネットで、ひと月ほど調査しているのですがいまだに復旧できていないので、こちらのサイトを利用させていただきました。

現在の状態ですが、ネットワークドライブの追加を行うと、エラーになります。
ネットワーク診断を行うと、以下の問題があるようでした。
＝＝＝
「リモートデバイスまたはリソースが接続を受け付けてません」
デバイスまたはリソース（サーバIP）は、ポート”ファイルとプリンターの共有（SMB）”で接続を受け付けるように設定されていません。
＝＝＝

接続できなくなる前にやったことといえば、自分のパスワード変更くらいでしたので、
sambaサーバ側は問題ないだろうと考えています。

ネットで調べてみて、類似の問題を調べて、以下リンクのことを試しましたが、改善しませんでした。
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1076338775
実施内容
→ 「ネットワーク探索」を有効に。
→ 「ファイルとプリンタの共有」を有効に。
→ 「ハブリックフォルダの共有」を有効に。
→ 「ファイル共有の接続」は「40ビット」に。
※パスワード保護共有は設定する項目が見当たらなかったので、有効か無効かわかりません。

なおパスワード変更は、以下の手順で行いました。
＝＝＝
1.[ctrl]+[alt]+[delete]を押して、メニュー？からパスワードの変更を選択

2.古いパスワードと新しいパスワードを入力して、パスワードを変更
＝＝＝

その他以下を確認しています。
～～～～～
1.
別の検証用PC（社内NWにはつながるwindows server2008r2）にて、
\sambaサーバIP\共有ディレクトリ
を実行すると、認証画面が出てきて、今のユーザ・パスワードを入力すると、sambaサーバに正常につながりました。

2.
コマンドプロンプトで以下を確認
※aaa.bbb.ccc.dddはsambaサーバIP
■自身PC
「ネットワークパスが見つかりません。」となり、接続できませんでした。
＝＝＝＝＝
C:\Users\hoge.hoge>\aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
ファイル名、ディレクトリ名、またはボリューム ラベルの構文が間違っています。

C:\Users\hoge.hoge>\aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd\Backup
ネットワーク パスが見つかりません。

C:\Users\hoge.hoge>NET USE \aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd\
システム エラー 53 が発生しました。

ネットワーク パスが見つかりません。

C:\Users\hoge.hoge>NET USE \aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd\backup
システム エラー 53 が発生しました。

ネットワーク パスが見つかりません。
＝＝＝＝＝

3.
以下の参考URL先の情報を確認し、以下を実施しましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。
http://okwave.jp/qa/q6037724.html

「ipconfig /all」とデバイスマネージャで、ネットワーク アダプターの配下を見てみましたが、
6TO4の文字列を含むアダプタがなかったので、以下の2つを無効にしましたが、状況変わりませんでした。
＝＝＝＝＝
Microsoft ISATAP Adapterを無効。
Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interfaceを無効。
＝＝＝＝＝

～～～～～

■検証PC
こちらは、現在のパスワードで、Dirコマンドまで正常に行えました。
＝＝＝＝＝
C:\Users\Administrator>\aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
ファイル名、ディレクトリ名、またはボリューム ラベルの構文が間違っています。

C:\Users\Administrator>\aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd\Backup
ログオン失敗: ユーザー名を認識できないか、またはパスワードが間違っています。

C:\Users\Administrator>Net USE \aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd\Backup
'aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd' のユーザー名を入力してください: ドメイン名\ユーザー名
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd のパスワードを入力してください:
コマンドは正常に終了しました。
＝＝＝＝＝
～～～

Answer (score 1):

認証キャッシュの削除な気がしますが、`smb.conf` もしくは `smb4.conf` なしではどんな構成にしたかもわかりません。

参照: 「[winbindにてSID / UID,GID間の紐付けがおかしくなった場合の対処方法](http://extrea.hatenablog.com/entry/2012/01/13/234810)」

`smbd-V` で samba バージョンを調べた上で「samba ActiveDirectory　参加」もしくは「samba4 ActiveDirectory　参加」で検索するとファイルサーバをActiveDirectoryに参加させる方法がみつかるので、再度参加させるのが手っ取り早いかとはおもいます

ただし、どちらにしても UID, GID のマッピング情報をバックアップしないと悲惨な事なるので idmap について自分の設定ファイルを見ながらマニュアルを熟読して下さい。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

バージョン確認したところ、3.5.6でした。
キャッシュファイルを探しましたが、/etc/cache/sambaは空でした。

また、設定ファイルですが、コメント欄に書こうとすると文字数をオーバーする為、
分割させていただきます。
＝＝＝ここから＝＝＝
[global]
passdb backend = tdbsam
printing = bsd
invalid users = @HOGEHOGE\\HOGE-InvalidUsers @HOGEHOGE\\一般Grp

;workgroup = HOGEHOGE

realm = HOGEHOGE.COM

security = ads

ldap ssl = no

add user script = useradd -m -s /bin/false %u

;winbind
idmap uid = 10000-12000
idmap gid = 10000-12000

obey pam restrictions = no
winbind normalize names = yes

Comment: create krb5 conf = yes
ctdb timeout = 0
cups encrypt = no
debug hires timestamp =  yes
ldap deref = auto
ldap follow referral =  auto
nmbd bind explicit broadcast = no
wide links =  no

;idmap backend =
winbind enum groups = yes

smb ports = 139
socket address = 172.16.100.202

socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192

client use spnego = no
server signing = auto
client signing = auto

unix extensions = no

store dos attributes = yes
map archive = no
workgroup = hogehoge
server string = Samba Server Version %v
unix charset = UTF-8
dos charset = CP932
display charset = UTF-8

Comment: #username map=/etc/samba/smbusers
load printers=no
disable spoolss=yes
printing=bsd
[Backup]
comment=Backup
path=/data_raid6
#path = /test_raid1
writable = yes
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 0755
;vfs objects = recycle
;recycle:keeptree = yes
;recycle:versions = yes
;recycle:touch = yes
;recycle:repository = .recycle.%U
veto files = /Software
[Software]
comment = Software
path = /data_raid6/Software
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
;vfs objects = recycle
;recycle:keeptree = yes
;recycle:versions = yes
;recycle:touch = yes
;recycle:repository = .recycle.%U
＝＝ここまで＝＝